# C++ template - several specializations - is behaviour defined?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Let's imagine I declare a templated structure:

```
template <int N> struct mystruct;
```

Let's imagine my structure has a general behavior for all `N`, except when `N == 0`

I can declare for instance a special behavior for `N == 0` with:

```
template<> struct mystruct<0> {int k = 0};
```

I can also declare the general behaviour with:

```
template<int N> struct mystruct {float k = 3.14;};
```

If I run in the main:

```
struct mystruct<-1> x;
struct mystruct<0> y;
struct mystruct<1> z;
std::cout << x.k << " " << y.k << " " << z.k << std::endl;
```

I get what I want : `3.14 0 3.14`, whatever the order of template declarations.

However I am wondering if this behavior is insured. Indeed, when I declare:

`struct mystruct<0> y;`

In my mind, this could as well be defined by both `mystruct` implementations.

So the question is:

*Does C++ normalization ensure the template specialization `<0>` to override the general basic implementation `<int N>`, whatever the templates specialization order in the code is?*

Comment: Short answer: Yes, that's the whole point of specializations.

Comment: There is only one specialization here, `mystruct<0>`. The other variant is just a main template itself.

Comment: It's guaranteed, as long as it can see it. You can have very real situations where you have some primary template, a header that specializes it for some type `Foo`, and then some client of this primary template somehow doesn't include the header doing the specializing behavior. If the primary and specializations are all in one header, this can't happen, but it can come up often when template specialization is used as a customization point for libraries. Thought, careful design, and documentation for your users is required for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 5):

For your particular case, because the specialization *has* to appear after the primary template, and assuming they *both* appear, then yes. Otherwise, if one TU sees the specialization, but another doesn't and they both use `mystruct<0>`, you'd get undefined behavior.

In the general case, with many specializations that may be quite complicated, the C++ standard has this to say at [[temp.expl.spec]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#7), emphasis mine:

> The placement of explicit specialization declarations for function
>   templates, class templates, variable templates, member functions of
>   class templates, static data members of class templates, member
>   classes of class templates, member enumerations of class templates,
>   member class templates of class templates, member function templates
>   of class templates, static data member templates of class templates,
>   member functions of member templates of class templates, member
>   functions of member templates of non-template classes, static data
>   member templates of non-template classes, member function templates of
>   member classes of class templates, etc., and the placement of partial
>   specialization declarations of class templates, variable templates,
>   member class templates of non-template classes, static data member
>   templates of non-template classes, member class templates of class
>   templates, etc., can affect whether a program is well-formed according
>   to the relative positioning of the explicit specialization
>   declarations and their points of instantiation in the translation unit
>   as specified above and below. **When writing a specialization, be
>   careful about its location; or to make it compile will be such a trial
>   as to kindle its self-immolation.**

Comment: Bold font spoils the Easter egg.

Comment: @PeteBecker Well, reading the whole list of different template types is quite daunting (I stopped counting the appearances of "template" after a while...). Didn't want the OP to miss the point. And yes, it's a fantastic quote. Was dying to use it in an answer some day. Item off the bucket list.

Comment: Wouldn't have expected to see humor in the C++ standard :)

Comment: Then what could lead to undefined behavior in the context of my example?

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois - In the context of your example, if one translation unit would have seen the specialization, but a second one didn't, and they both would have used the template `mystruct<0>`. That's UB right there.

Comment: @StoryTeller -- yes, it's daunting. That's the point. And that's part of the reason I decided not to remove it, despite it's lack of serious technical content.

Answer (score 3):

> Does C++ normalization ensure the template specialization `<0>` to override the general construction `<N>`, whatever the templates specialization order in the code is?

Just to clarify on terminology,

```
template<int N> struct mystruct {float k = 3.14;};
```

is not a specialization. It is the main/generic/base implementation.

The specialization `mystruct<0>` will be used whenever an `mystruct<0>` is used as long as the specialization is visible at the point `mystruct<0>` is used. That's the whole point of specialization.